# Topic does not match an authorized rule

Tags: raspberry-pi, ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot, publish

the following code is what i used to publish data from my r-pi sense-hat to the IBM cloud

```
topic = 'iot-2/evt/temperature/fmt/json'
print("Publishing data from pito cloud",json.dumps(payload))
client.publish(topic,json.dumps(payload), qos=1)
```

Has the format for publishing changed on the IBM Cloud?
IBM cloud connection log gave the message: Topic does not match authorized rule.

Answer (score 2):

If you are publishing events connected as a device (e.g. clientId = **d:{orgId}:{typeId}:{deviceId}**) that is the correct topic:

```
iot-2/evt/temperature/fmt/json
```

If you are publishing events connected as an application (e.g. clientId = **a:{orgId}:{appId}**) the topic structure you need to use is different:

```
iot-2/type/{typeId}/id/{deviceId}/evt/temperature/fmt/json
```

Looks like you are using the Python paho client, if you are using Python I highly recommend giving official SDK **wiotp-sdk** package a try, it masks all the internal details of the MQTT & HTTP APIs such as which topic strings to use.

The code is open source in [GitHub](https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-python), available from [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/wiotp-sdk/) and used extensively by the Watson IoT Platform development team for all our internal monitoring agents.

The relevant code for event publication for applications and devices are below, even if you don't want to use the SDK these may be of help to you to see how the underlying Paho client is being used:

- [wiotp/sdk/device/client.py#L90](https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-python/blob/30dc9eb9b025d0962085063a969f257e6cfd647b/src/wiotp/sdk/device/client.py#L90)
- [wiotp/sdk/application/client.py#L165](https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-python/blob/30dc9eb9b025d0962085063a969f257e6cfd647b/src/wiotp/sdk/application/client.py#L165)